# MySql - Is there a queries queue somewhare

Tags: mysql, queue

I used a loop in my php script to run insert queries into my db. The loop was looping thousand times. I stop my php script while it was till running. Nevertheless, my db table keeps on getting populated continously. I guess that there must be a queue. but this is only a guess. So I am wondering if I can stop all the pending queries from being executed? Also I am wondering if it is possible to see that queue somewhere? Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

Comment: Did you stop it by pressing "stop" in the browser or by actually killing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no queue, unless you were using `INSERT DELAYED`.

You can kill the process that is inserting the data like this:

Run [`SHOW PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html) to find the id of the connecton you want to kill

Then run [`KILL CONNECTION <thread_id>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html) to kill that connection.

Comment: Hello Ike. From where and how do i run this show processlist command? Thanks

Comment: You can run it at the MySQL prompt: `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`. I included a link to the documentation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` will give you a list of all currently running queries