# Does my query lock the row for the next use

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my code structure in php:

```
function myfunction(){

    try{    
        // begin Transaction

        // get last row by this query:
        // SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE t_date+INTERVAL 1 MINUTE< NOW() LIMIT 1
        // store the returned id inside $id if exists, $id=0 otherwise (out of id for now)

        // update the row to the current time to show it is fetched now by this query:
        // UPDATE tableNAME SET t_date=NOW() WHERE id=$id

        // end of Transaction
        // commit   

    }catch (PDOException $e){
        // failed, rollback
        $id = 0;
    }

    return $id
}
```

As you can see, myfunction:

1. used transaction to lock the row.
2. returns unique row id that hasn't been returned in the last 1 minute.
3. requested user owns that id for 1 minute.
4. other users can own that id after 1 minute.

Code works without any problem and I don't have any issues related to the code structure.

**The question**

As you can see the id should always be unique for each request. I'm using MySQL and want to know:

If two users (or more) open a page at the same time and because:

- they have different PDO connection and
- MySQL can run two or more requests simultaneously in different threads and
- since I isolate the fetching query inside transaction,

Do I always have unique result as I expected?

I've read @symcbean answer about [Does MySQL queue queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16119445/5617911) and he mentioned:

> It's very improbable that 2 queries could arrive at the same time -
>   but not impossible

Does my code structure helps me to avoid parallel queries?

Comment: Why can't you do this in one statement?

Comment: @tadman does it avoid parallel queries for different connections?

Comment: You're talking about [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). If you express this as a single statement that can run atomically then there's no risk of that. A single `UPDATE` with the associated `WHERE` and `LIMIT` conditions could do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the scenario where two queries arrive at the same time, all the transaction does is guarantee ACID behavior for each thread's database operations.  It does not mean that the two sets of select/update could not happen at the same time; this could in fact happen.

One way to deal with this would be to use [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html):

```
SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE t_date + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE < NOW() LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE tableNAME SET t_date=NOW() WHERE id = $id;
```

The `FOR UPDATE` clause will tell MySQL to lock down the single matching `id` row, such that even if another thread came in, it would not be able to lock, and therefore could not update.

**Edit:**

AS @tadman has pointed out, you might even be able to just use a single query here:

```
UPDATE tableNAME
SET t_date = NOW()
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM tableName WHERE t_date + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE < NOW() LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: To be clear, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` would be done within a transaction.